# Xamarinのjarの組込みでクラス内に同名のプロパティとクラスがある場合

Tags: android, java, c#, visual-studio, xamarin

プリンタ機器メーカー提供のSDK(jar)を使用してプリンタにデータを送信しようとしています。
開発はXamarin Androidなので、
Visual Studioの"Binding Library (Android)"プロジェクトを作成してBrotherPrintLibrary.jarのラッパーdllを作成しました。
バインディングプロジェクト自体は正常にビルドでき、
そのdllをXamarin Androidのプロジェクトから参照できましたが

どうもCom.Brother.Ptouch.Sdk.PrinterInfoというクラスのPortプロパティが欠落しています。

元々PrinterInfoクラス内にPortという列挙用クラスとPortというプロパティがあったようで
名前かぶっているのでプロパティの方が消滅したようです。
（特にビルドでは何もなく・・・）

最終的に生成されるプロパティの名前がPort1でもなんでも良く、
内部的にPortプロパティに値がセットできればいいのですが
バインディングプロジェクトでこのプロパティの名前を変えるとかできないでしょうか。

対応方法を教えて頂けると幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: jarファイルを展開して、中のjavaファイルを修正し、再度jar化して、ラッパーdllを作り直せばどうでしょうか(`jar xvf hoge.jar`で展開。`jar cMvf hoge.jar dir1 dir2 ...`で圧縮)

Comment: KNaitoさん
ご回答ありがとうございます。
jarファイルを展開して該当の.classファイルを逆コンパイルしてみました。
すると今回設定したい値が初期値設定されていることがわかりましたので今回プロパティが無くなっていますが、それに値をセットしなければならない問題は回避されました。

ただ問題は全く解決されていませんので他の値にする時はどうなんだということになります。
教えて頂いた方法は有効かもしれません。
ただし公開されているSDKを改変するのは権利的な問題がありそうです。

ひとまず
道を開いていただきありがとうございました。

もしXamarinなどラッパ側で可能な方法がありそうでしたらご紹介ください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xamarin の Java Binding 機能は、 `Transforms` ディレクトリに XMLファイルを配置することで、生成後のAPIを変更することができます。

- [Java Bindings Metadata - Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding-a-java-library/customizing-bindings/java-bindings-metadata/)

この機能のサンプルがいくつかあるようですので、参考になると思います。

- [Samples - Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/android/Binding%20+%20Interop/)

Comment: amay077さん
解決です。
今回の対応の仕方は
バインディングプロジェクト**/Transforms/Metadata.xml**に次の１行を追加しました。
'<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.brother.ptouch.sdk']/class[@name='PrinterInfo']/field[@name='port']" name="managedName">PortValue</attr>'

これによってPrinterInfo.Portとなるはずだった名前がPrinterInfo.PortValueという名前のプロパティとして作成されるようになります。

Xamarinの説明をみてそれっぽいことは書いてあると思いましたが理解に至りませんでしたが、Xamarinのサンプルを見る事でわかりました。

ありがとうございます。